# local storage and session storage

Tags: jquery, html

I'm taking my first step of a thousand miles with the new local storage and session storage found in html5.

[`http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/`](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/)

Q: Is there a code example of using either session storage or local storage, where the user enters a value, the value is saved locally, the user then connects to the Internet on his 56K modem and the local storage is synced with a server?

Comment: HTML5 offline stuff are all client side, not server side.  You'll need to write some JS to sync with server side DB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can find an example [on this page on hacks.mozilla.org](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/01/offline-web-applications/)

Comment: Thanks futtta.   This will get me to take another step.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the setInterval and blindly trying to send data to your server, check the navigator.onLine property:

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
   // Send data using XMLHttpRequest
} else {
   // Queue data locally to send later
}
```

You can also add listeners to the Window object for the "online" and "offline" events which will let you know when the browser has internet connectivity again.

Comment: Thanks Arne!  I'm looking for a code example, so your answer is a good first step.

Comment: +1 nice one. Is DOM0 but not standard.. How is browser support here? Doc here btw: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.navigator.onLine

Comment: Tested navigator.onLine successfully with Firefox 3.6, Safari 4, IE8, and Chrome 5 (dev) and I hear it's in Opera too.

Answer (score 4):

These libraries belong here...

- https://github.com/andris9/jStorage
- https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js
- https://github.com/ZaDarkSide/simpleStorage

Comment: Thanks doublejosh.  I had never seen these before.